# Turing Machine for $L = \{ a^ib^j \mid 0 \lt i \lt j \}$.

Tags: turing-machines

I would have a brief question about how to construct a Turing machine that is accepting only this language:

w E L = { aibj   |  0 < i < j  }.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Edit: L = { a^ib^j | 0 < i < j }.

Comment: You can edit your own question, just click the "edit" button below the post, next to the "share", "follow", "delete", and so on (not always available on mobile, though).

Comment: You should use LaTeX. Also what kind of Turing machine do you need? There are many kinds (deterministic, non-deterministic, with one tape, with many tapes, etc,).